# How to redirect when ActionNotFound in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a controller `SubscriptionsController` with only actions `new` and `create`. How would I redirect to `new` if say someone tries to visit `GET /subscriptions` which would normally trigger the `index` action?

*config/routes.rb*

`resource :subscriptions, :only => [:new, :create]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rails3 you can do it from a route, something like:

```
match "/subscriptions", :to => redirect("/subscriptions/new")
```

Edit:

From the comments it was made clear you want to capture more than that, using a wild card you can make it more generic. You may need to combine this form with the previous to deal with the non-slash form (or try the below form without a slash, I havent tried that). Also make sure to put these "catch all" routes below your other ones since routes are matched from top to bottom.

```
match "/subscriptions/*other", :to => redirect("/subscriptions/new")
```

Comment: Sure, I could hardcode that. But then I have to do that for all PUT and DELETE requests for `/subscrptions/1` and `/subscriptions/1/edit` etc. Basically I want a "catch-all" for all routes not found, redirect to `subscriptions#new`

Comment: `match "/subscriptions/*other"` and place it after your other routes.

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I've got as the last route `match '*other', :to => redirect('/')`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you meant absolute all other URLs! Glad thats working for you!